# What will be the time complexity of the following nested loopin Big O notation?

Tags: c, time-complexity

Was wondering what is the time complexity of the following code:

```
int i,j,n,p,s=0;
scanf("%d",&n);
p = pow(3, n);
for(i=0; i<p; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        s+=j;
    }
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

In my opinion, the time complexity will be n*(3^n).

What will it be in Big-O notation, what do you guys think ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is `O((3^n)*n)`.
Outer loop iterates `3^n` times, each time, the inner loop does `O(n)` work.

Comment: @DanielPryden Asymptotically concerning what? For very high `n`? I myself am lousy at big O determination, but I find OPs guess and Tonys reasoning convincing. Please elaborate your comment.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Do you understand what an asymptote is? As N goes to infinity, the higher-ordered coefficient dominates more and more until it becomes the only term that matters. That's how big O bounds are typically used. If you want a tight bound on actual execution time, that's big Theta.

Comment: O(3^N) is definitely not correct.  There is no constant you can multiply 3^N by such that it will be larger than N*3^N for sufficiently high N.

Comment: @DanielPryden I spotted my mistake. It was a smaller mistake than what you guessed, more silly though. I simply mixed up `3^N` and `N^3`.

Comment: @DanielPryden After disqualifying myself, I would like to read your opinion on the input by QuestionC.

Comment: Isn't  `(3^N)*N==exp(N/ln(3)+ln(N))==3^(N+ln(3)*ln(N))`? Wouldn't that mean this gets to be O(3^(N+ln(N)*ln(3)) ) or O(3^(N+ln(N)))? I am unsure about dropping the factor ln(3) and whether it is considered bigger than O(3^N).

Comment: @DanielPryden & Yunnosch.
QuestionC comment sums it up really.

Comment: I think I had confused myself into thinking that the bound was `O(3 ^ (N+1))` which would still be within `O(3^N)` (asymptotically speaking). But now I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @DanielPryden that is obviously incorrect. `3^(N+1)` = `3*(3^N)` which is `O(3^N)`

Comment: @TonyTannous: I agree with you, both that I was incorrect and that `O(3^(N+1)) = O(3^N)`.